# How service can identify controller

Tags: java, spring

I have Spring boot application with such case:

```
Controller A { service.call()}
Controller B { service.call()}
```

Depends on which controller was used i need to implement custom logic in service. Does spring ecosystem let do it without any external methods, like IDs, different service implementations etc.

How can i make service know which controller, A or B was used?

Comment: Bad design.  The services shouldn't know or care who is calling them.

Answer (score 2):

You could work around this issue with reflective tricks, but there's really no reason to. The solution is simple: If you need different functionality, have different methods:

```
class SomeService {
  void callFromA() {
    // A specific stuff
    call()
  }

  void callFromB() {
    // B specific stuff
    call()
  }

  private void call() { 
    // shared logic
  }
}
```

Update: I assumed this was obvious, but here's now you use it:

```
class ControllerA {
  private final SomeService service;
  void someMethod() { service.callFromA(); }
}
class ControllerB {
  private final SomeService service;
  void someMethod() { service.callFromB(); }
}
```

Comment: And how SomeService would know, when it should apply callFromA or callFromB methods? In my case it's based on what controller was called

Comment: @danilakds The service doesn't know. The controllers know.

Comment: yep, understand. Thanks for help

Comment: Yes. Alternatively, you could add an argument to method `call` and pass some value from `ControllerA` and another value from `ControllerB`

Answer (score -2):

I don't have any idea about the Spring ecosystem, but there is a solution in Java itself.

```
public class SomeService {

     public void someMethod(){

       // this will fetch all the information about current thread
       StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();

       // third element of the array will contain caller class name
       String callerClassName = stackTrace[2].getClassName();

       // now you can perform whatever operation based on callerClassName
       if(callerClassName.equals("A")){
          //doThis
       }else{
          //doThat
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: With the caveat that if you’re doing this there’s a reasonable chance something has gone wrong during design. There are legitimate uses of this, the OP’s use case shouldn’t be one of them ;)